# Definer error while setting up a replica in google cloud sql with an external source mysql

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql, database-replication

We're setting up a replica in google cloud sql of a MySQL hosted somewhere else.

While checking why the replication fails we get this:

```
{
  "kind": "sql#externalSyncSettingErrorList",
  "errors": [
    {
      "kind": "sql#externalSyncSettingError",
      "type": "UNSUPPORTED_DEFINER",
      "detail": "Definer user root@localhost not supported. Please update host to '%'."
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm not changing the host on the root to '%' ... Any tips on how to get around this issue without touching the source server ?

Answer (score 0):

The following examples demonstrate how the DEFINER can be removed in Linux, macOS, or Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL):

Remove

```
sed -i -e 's/DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`//g' dump.sql
```

Find and replace

```
sed -i -e 's/DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`/DEFINER=`masteruser`@`%`/g' dump.sql
```

Note: Replace the value for **masteruser** with the name of your MySql master user.

then restore on replica (google cloud sql).

Answer (score 0):

You have to analyse all definers in your source. You can do that running the following SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DEFINER FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.EVENTS;
SELECT DISTINCT DEFINER FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES;
SELECT DISTINCT DEFINER FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TRIGGERS;
SELECT DISTINCT DEFINER FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS;
```

If you see that something (procedure, function, view, trigger, event) has a definer with host equals to localhost (e.g. root@localhost), change these definers to another user. I had on my source database root@localhost and root@10.%, both users having the same privileges, then I simply changed the definers to root@10.% using a phpMyAdmin.